# Как получить значение из файла build.prop?

Tags: android

Мне нужно получить значения без редактирование из файла `/system/build.prop`.
Эти значения выводятся через `adb shell getprop`, но мне нужно получить эти значения в коде.

Решил таким путём

```
input = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/getprop").getInputStream();
str = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А просто взять и открыть этот файл и вычитать? Ну как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579885/determine-opencore-or-stagefright-framework-for-mediaplayer).

Comment: всё решил проблему,я думал просто файл закрытый нельзя просто так прочитать.